# Second Apache virtual host not loading

Tags: php, apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I have Apache installed on a Ubuntu 20.04 server and it was working fine. And then I started to mess around with virtual hosts because I wanted to add a subdomain.

My goal is to have two separate projects accessible on two separate URLs:

- Main project - `example.com`
- Sub project - `subdomain.example.com`

On my file server I have these file structure:

```
- /var/www/html
  - index.php
- /var/www/subdomain.example.com
  - index.php
```

On `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf` I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I ran the following commands after saving the file:

```sh
# Enable the new Apache configuration
sudo a2ensite example.conf

# Disable the default Apache configuration
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf

# Activate the new Apache configuration
sudo systemctl reload apache2

# Restart Apache server
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Once that's all done, I go visit `http://example.com` and it works fine. But when I visit `http://subdomain.example.com` I get the following error in Chrome:

> subdomain.example.com's server IP address could not be found.

I went ahead and edited `/etc/hosts` and have the following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 subdomain.example.com
```

I'm not sure if I need to do anything after modifying `/etc/hosts` but no changes even after I saved the new hosts file.

How do I fix my virtual hosts so that I end up with the goal I mentioned at the beginning of this question?

Comment: can you show the output from `httpd -D DUMP_VHOSTS`

Comment: @Raxi I am getting Command `'httpd' not found, did you mean:

  command 'http' from deb httpie (1.0.3-2)
  command 'xttpd' from deb xtide (2.13.2-1build2)

Try: apt install <deb name>`

Comment: Try `apache -D DUMP_VHOSTS` instead (or otherwise apache2 maybe), i guess it has a different name on your distro

Comment: If you mean that Chrome cannot resolve the IP address for `subdomain.example.com` despite having added it to `/etc/hosts`, perhaps it isn't fetching fresh info after initial failure, or perhaps there's something wrong in the file. Can you resolve the IP with another tool, such as `host subdomain.example.com`? (Nothing of this should be related to Apache anyway.)

Comment: @Raxi I am getting: `dokgu@example:/var/www$ apache2 -D DUMP_VHOSTS
[Thu Dec 30 17:49:58.265327 2021] [core:warn] [pid 21637] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot`

Comment: _I'm not sure if I need to do anything after modifying /etc/hosts_ — "Modifications  to  this  file  normally take effect immediately, except in cases where the file is cached by applications." ([Source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/hosts.5.html))

Comment: i see now. The 3 lines in the `hosts` file should be on one line. `127.0.0.1 localhost example.com subdomain.example.com`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález this is what I get: `dokgu@example:/var/www$ host subdomain.example.com
subdomain.example.com has address 127.0.0.1
Host subdomain.example.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

Comment: @Raxi I changed it to a single line like you suggested but it still doesn't load.. the primary domain works though.

Comment: what does `nslookup subdomain.example.com` say ?

Comment: @Raxi I get: `dokgu@example:/var/www$ nslookup subdomain.example.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   subdomain.example.com
Address: 127.0.0.1`

Comment: k, so the `hosts`file part works; can you try `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`

Comment: @Raxi `dokgu@charkath:/var/www$ sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf:1)
                 alias www.example.com
         port 80 namevhost subdomain.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf:10)
                 alias www.subdomain.example.com`

Comment: Odd, that seems alright too. Are you sure you havent accidentally set the documentroot in the subdomain-vhost to the one from the main vhost ? or maybe some rewriterules or .htaccess shenanigans ?

Comment: @Raxi I haven't started using `.htaccess` files yet. There's really only `index.php` on each document root. And the `DocumentRoot` directive is set up exactly as in the question.

Comment: Strange, can't think of what it could be serverside then. Maybe its your browser ? can you try `CTRL+F5` on the subdomain page; and maybe clear the browser cache and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the issue isn't with how Apache is configured.

On the `Cloud DNS` from the Google Cloud Platform dashboard I had to add two record sets:

- `A` record `subdomain.example.com` with the correct IP address
- `CNAME` record `www.subdomain.example.com`

And now it works.